# Android coroutine job changed to CompletableJob?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I update my project coroutines to the newer version all my job creation with launch scope are failing...

on gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.2'
```

The error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Job but CompletableJob was expected
```

Code:

```
var websiteCrawlerResultList: ArrayList<WebsiteCrawlerResult> = arrayListOf()
    var url: URL? = null
    private var urlList: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()
    private var job = Job()
    private var scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default+job)

    fun startCrawler() {
        job = scope.launch {
            crawlPageLinks(url)
            Log.d(TAG, "Finished ${url.toString()} crawling")
        }
    }
```

when `job = scope.launch {` Android Studio return the type mismatch error, he expect to be `CompletableJob`, but I not using it and this don't exists on the old version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Job()` is actually a factory function that returns a `CompletableJob`. Therefore the type of `private var job = Job()` is `CompletableJob`. However, the return type for `scope.launch` is just a `Job`. You get an error because not all `Job` instances are `CompletableJob` instances.

Instead of relying on type inference (and the automatically assigned `CompletableJob` type), you can specify the exact type you want to use:

```
private var job: Job = Job()
```